# How to check if mouse is in View3D Window from modal operator (2.80)

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, add-on, development

In the context of a modal operator, I would like to perform an operation when the left mouse button is clicked in the `VIEW_3D` area, `WINDOW` region. (similar to setting the cursor location with a mouse left click, assuming 'right click select' is enabled)

So far I have the following code:

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

def mouse_in_view3d_window(event):
    regions = dict()
    for region in bpy.context.area.regions:
        regions[region.type] = region
    mouse_pos = Vector((event.mouse_x, event.mouse_y))
    window_dimensions = Vector((
        regions["WINDOW"].width - regions["UI"].width,
        regions["WINDOW"].height - regions["HEADER"].height
    ))
    return (
        regions["TOOLS"].width < mouse_pos.x < window_dimensions.x and
        mouse_pos.y < window_dimensions.y
    )

class SCENE_OT_set_cursor_in_view3d_window(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ Test operator for 'mouse_in_view3d_window' function """
    bl_idname = "scene.set_cursor_in_view3d_window"
    bl_label = "Set Cursor"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if bpy.context.area is None:
            return {"PASS_THROUGH"}
        if mouse_in_view3d_window(event):
            bpy.context.window.cursor_set("PAINT_BRUSH")
        else:
            bpy.context.window.cursor_set("DEFAULT")

        return {"PASS_THROUGH"}

    def execute(self, context):
        # run modal operator
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SCENE_OT_set_cursor_in_view3d_window)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

This gets me close, but still returns `False` when the mouse is in the dead space below the `UI` and `Tools` regions, as well as the dead space between header buttons:

[image: 3D View regions ignored]

Is there a way to improve my `mouse_in_view3d_window` function to account for these additional areas? Blender seems to accomplish this internally, as mouse clicks in these areas are passed through to the viewport (e.g. clicking in 3D space to set the cursor location).

Thanks for your help!